# Problems by adding attachment to MimeKit mail in Android

Tags: forms, xamarin, attachment, mimekit

I try to add an attachment to mail which should be sent via MimeKit on Xamarin Forms.

```
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test", "Test@gmail.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Linde", To));
        message.Subject = Subject;

        var builder = new BodyBuilder();

        // Set the plain-text version of the message text
        builder.TextBody = @"Example text
                ";

        // We may also want to attach a calendar event for Monica's party...
        builder.Attachments.Add(@"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.plugin.mediatest/files/Pictures/temp/IMG.jpg");
```

The last row throughs the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.plugin.mediatest/files/Pictures/temp/IMG.jpg"
>   is denied.

I set the following permission to get access to the picture-file:

"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

But this doesn't take effect on accessing the file.
In the run-up to the "builder.Attachments"-row I checked, whether the file exists, and it does.

Are there any other permissions I have to request?

Comment: Is `com.plugin.mediatest` the app that this code context is executing in? If so, are you defining a file provider in your Android application project? FYI: Do not hard code that path `/storage/emulated/0/.... as it will change from device to device (depending upon API level, OEM firmware, etc...)

Comment: The file I like to send is originally created by xamarin Media plugin. The plugin stores it in the previously mentioned path. What does the file provider do and how can I include it to be able to get access to the stored picture with my body builder?